# Select IDs even when there is no data in a 'JOIN'ed table

Tags: sql, join

I'd like to achieve something I believe is fairly easy, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have two tables, A and B:

Table A is where all the items are defined.

```
+----+--------------+
+ ID + other_things +
+----+--------------+
+ 1  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
+ 2  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
+ 3  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
+----+--------------+
```

In Table B, some optional properties are stored, but not all the records are in this table.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ ID + prop_type   +  prop_value +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 1  +    prop1    +   foo       +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 1  +    prop2    +   toto      +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 3  +    prop2    +  lorem      +
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

When I query those tables, using:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.prop_value FROM A FULL JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE B.prop_type = 'prop2'
```

I get

```
ID                       prop_value
------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------
1                        toto
3                        lorem
```

But I'd like to get all the lines in table A, even if they dont have a 'prop2' value, something like

```
ID                       prop_value
------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------
1                        toto
2                   
3                        lorem
```

How can I tweak my query to get the latter (I think it has to do with the JOIN keywords, but no matter how many tutorials I read, I can't make it work...)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not using `MySQL` if you are using `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: Correct, it's SQLPlus, I removed the tag for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `where`, use `and`:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.prop_value FROM A FULL JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID and B.prop_type = 'prop2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need a `LEFT JOIN` for this.  The key is to put the `WHERE` condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.prop_value
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.prop_type = 'prop2';
```

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, even when there are no matching rows in the second.  However, the values of the columns in the second table are then `NULL`, so the `WHERE` clause filters them out.

As I note in the comment, MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  Most databases do, but `LEFT JOIN` is still the appropriate join type for what you want to do.